# Is there a conditional assignment shorthand in javascript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Can this be done in javascript

python code:

```
value = value if value else "Oompa Loompa"
```

Update:

the duplicate solution proposed does not answer my question, i would like something similar to what python does in js if possible, i have supplied another example for python below:

```
value = value if value >= 5 else 0
```

Comment: ternary operator?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: so quick at down voting, should be some type of protection, see update to my question

Comment: value = (value >= 5) ? value : 0; https://jsfiddle.net/04ehtdqr/

Answer (score 5):

you can do something like

`value = value || "Oompa Loompa"`

or

`value = value ? value: "Oompa Loompa"`

Comment: I fail to comprehend why people downvote this

Comment: I don't know :)

Comment: so quick at down voting, should be some type of protection, see update to my question

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the ternary operator:

```
value = value ? value : "Oompa Loompa"
```